# Hints in IntelliSense from ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense, hints

If IntelliSense from Visual Studio (Menu RESHARPER-> Options ... -> IntelliSense and select Visual Studio), then the drop-down menu has hints.
If IntelliSense from ReSharper (Menu RESHARPER-> Options ... -> IntelliSense and select ReSharper), the hints do not appear.

How to do that in the case of ReSharper IntelliSense worked tips (hint)?

IntelliSense from Visual Studio:

[Visual Studio http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130319/n0UQD0fs.png](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130319/n0UQD0fs.png)

IntelliSense from ReSharper:

[ReSharper http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130319/zTR8z8uB.png](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130319/zTR8z8uB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | Completion Appearance -> Show member signatures` and maybe `Show summary`.